# Programatically set the username and password of a DataSource

Tags: java, spring, datasource

I need a datasource to pass into a Spring `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` so I can run a parametised query on it.

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
{
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.jdbcTemplateObject = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

Set<Integer> parameters = getSomeIds();
List<TableRow> rows = this.jdbcTemplateObject.query(config.getSql(), parameters, new TableRowMapper());
```

Now this is fine if I'm setting the username and password for the DataSource in the Spring Xml.

However, I need to dynamically assign these. How can I configure the username and password?

Comment: You mean you want to `@Inject` or `@Autowired` it? (Or you need the `@Value` of the username, password, ...?) I should mention that in case there are multiple `DataSource`s, you also need a `@Qualifier`. And probably a guide.

Comment: Don't use Spring XML - use Spring JavaConfig. Then _all_ your configuration would be programmatic and you wouldn't have these issues.

Answer (score 2):

It is done when obtaining the Connection from the DataSource with [`dataSource.getConnection(username, password)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). But since the JdbcTemplate is the one obtaining the connections from the DataSource for you, you'll need to encapsulate your DataSource in a [`UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.html), and pass the adapter to the JdbcTemplate.

```
UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter dsAdapter = new UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter();
dsAdapter.setTargetDataSource(dataSource);
dsAdapter.setUsername(username);
dsAdapter.setPassword(password);
this.jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dsAdapter);
```